# How to enable "Test drive now" in Amazon Appstore for Android?

Tags: amazon-appstore

I have searched and searched and I can not figure out how to enable the "Test drive now" feature on an app in Amazon's Appstore. I believe that I need to upload an additional APK built for x86 but I can't find any way to do that in the developer portal. Maybe the app APK needs both x86 and ARM (even if you don't use any NDK or native ARM code)? Or is it possibly an invite-only feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also searched and searched and could not find it as well.  So today, I just went through the developer contact amazon link and asked them to enable it on my app.  I provided a very short description of why I thought it would be good.  Within a couple of hours, Amazon enabled it on my app!!

I just used this link --> https://developer.amazon.com/help/contact-us.html

Comment: Oddly enough, it was suddenly enabled on my app too. It just showed up in the past day or two after being in their store for over a month. No special upload or anything and I didn't contact support about it. It definitely seems to have boosted sales so next time I'll be asking for it right away.